# With Rails Asset Pipeline, can I set YUI compressor to never keep CSS comments?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, yui-compressor

When minifying CSS, I do not want any CSS comments (`/* like this*/`) to end up in my production asset builds. However, they are still there. (And not just ones that start with `/*!`, as some documentation would suggest.)

Is there a way to change this?